# I need to add multiple checked radio values into a single variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables, checkbox

So I'm starting with JavaScript and I was trying to make a product selection form.

I want it to display the individual prices and then the total but problem comes when displaying the total, I have no idea how to make that function. Im not using JQuery by the way.
If you can come up with something it'll be really helpful. Thanks!

```js
//Pricelist
var aa = 7;
var ab = 5;

var ba = 1;
var bb = 3;
var bc = 5;

//Defined Variables
document.getElementById("Pizza").value = aa;
document.getElementById("Burguer").value = ab;

document.getElementById("Small").value = ba;
document.getElementById("Medium").value = bb;
document.getElementById("Large").value = bc;

//Display the prices
function decirValue() {
            if(document.getElementById('Pizza').checked) {
                document.getElementById("dispa").innerHTML
                    = document.getElementById("Pizza").value + "&nbsp;$ for the meal";
            }
            else if(document.getElementById('Burguer').checked) {
                document.getElementById("dispa").innerHTML
                    = document.getElementById("Burguer").value + "&nbsp;$ for the meal";
            }
            
            
            if(document.getElementById('Small').checked) {
                document.getElementById("dispb").innerHTML
                    = document.getElementById("Small").value + "&nbsp;$ for the size";
            }
            else if(document.getElementById('Medium').checked) {
                document.getElementById("dispb").innerHTML
                    = document.getElementById("Medium").value + "&nbsp;$ for the size";
            }
            else if(document.getElementById('Large').checked) {
                document.getElementById("dispb").innerHTML
                    = document.getElementById("Large").value + "&nbsp;$ for the size";
            }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <form id="jsform">
    
<h3>Select a meal</h3>
<input type="radio" class="stylebtn" name="food" id="Pizza" value="" checked="checked">Pizza<br>
<input type="radio" class="stylebtn" name="food" id="Burguer" value="">Burguer<br>

<h3>Select size</h3>
<input type="radio" class="stylebtn" name="dimensions" id="Small" value="" checked="checked">Small<br>
<input type="radio" class="stylebtn" name="dimensions" id="Medium" value="">Medium<br>
<input type="radio" class="stylebtn" name="dimensions" id="Large" value="">Large<br><br>

<button type="button" onclick="decirValue();">Submit</button>
<br>
<h4 id="dispa"></h4>
<h4 id="dispb"></h4>
<h4 id="totalprice">0 $</h4>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set a global variable and inside `function decirValue()` calculate the total price like following:

```js
//Pricelist
var aa = 7;
var ab = 5;

var ba = 1;
var bb = 3;
var bc = 5;

var totalPrice = 0;

//Defined Variables
document.getElementById("Pizza").value = aa;
document.getElementById("Burguer").value = ab;

document.getElementById("Small").value = ba;
document.getElementById("Medium").value = bb;
document.getElementById("Large").value = bc;

//Display the prices
function decirValue() {
            if(document.getElementById('Pizza').checked) {
                totalPrice += aa;
                document.getElementById("dispa").innerHTML
                    = document.getElementById("Pizza").value + "&nbsp;$ for the meal";
            }
            else if(document.getElementById('Burguer').checked) {
                totalPrice += ab;
                document.getElementById("dispa").innerHTML
                    = document.getElementById("Burguer").value + "&nbsp;$ for the meal";
            }
            
            
            if(document.getElementById('Small').checked) {
                totalPrice += ba;
                document.getElementById("dispb").innerHTML
                    = document.getElementById("Small").value + "&nbsp;$ for the size";
            }
            else if(document.getElementById('Medium').checked) {
                totalPrice += bb;

                document.getElementById("dispb").innerHTML
                    = document.getElementById("Medium").value + "&nbsp;$ for the size";
            }
            else if(document.getElementById('Large').checked) {
                totalPrice += bc;
                document.getElementById("dispb").innerHTML
                    = document.getElementById("Large").value + "&nbsp;$ for the size";
            }
       document.getElementById("totalprice").innerHTML = "total : " + totalPrice + " $";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <form id="jsform">
    
<h3>Select a meal</h3>
<input type="radio" class="stylebtn" name="food" id="Pizza" value="" checked="checked">Pizza<br>
<input type="radio" class="stylebtn" name="food" id="Burguer" value="">Burguer<br>

<h3>Select size</h3>
<input type="radio" class="stylebtn" name="dimensions" id="Small" value="" checked="checked">Small<br>
<input type="radio" class="stylebtn" name="dimensions" id="Medium" value="">Medium<br>
<input type="radio" class="stylebtn" name="dimensions" id="Large" value="">Large<br><br>

<button type="button" onclick="decirValue();">Submit</button>
<br>
<h4 id="dispa"></h4>
<h4 id="dispb"></h4>
<h4 id="totalprice">0 $</h4>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope be useful

Answer (score -1):

first of all, don't use variable names like `aa`, `bb`, etc. ([check me](https://devinduct.com/blogpost/22/javascript-clean-code-best-practices)) try also use ES6 variable declarations `const` and `let` ([read more](http://es6-features.org/#Constants)), also You can use `querySelector` to simplify Your code.

```js
//Pricelist
var pizzaPrice = 7;
var burgerPrice = 5;

var sizeSmall = 1;
var sizeMedium = 3;
var sizeLarge = 5;

//Defined Variables
document.getElementById("Pizza").value = pizzaPrice;
document.getElementById("Burguer").value = burgerPrice;

document.getElementById("Small").value = sizeSmall;
document.getElementById("Medium").value = sizeMedium;
document.getElementById("Large").value = sizeLarge;

//Display the prices
function decirValue() {
    const selectedFood = document.querySelector('[name="food"]:checked')
    document.getElementById("dispa").innerHTML = selectedFood.value + '&nbsp;$ for the meal'
            
  const selectedSize = document.querySelector('[name="dimensions"]:checked')
            document.getElementById("dispb").innerHTML = selectedSize.value + '&nbsp;$ for the size';
  
  const totalPrice = +selectedFood.value + +selectedSize.value;
    document.getElementById("totalprice").innerHTML = totalPrice + '&nbsp;$'
}
```

```html
<form id="jsform">
    
<h3>Select a meal</h3>
<input type="radio" class="stylebtn" name="food" id="Pizza" value="" checked="checked">Pizza<br>
<input type="radio" class="stylebtn" name="food" id="Burguer" value="">Burguer<br>

<h3>Select size</h3>
<input type="radio" class="stylebtn" name="dimensions" id="Small" value="" checked="checked">Small<br>
<input type="radio" class="stylebtn" name="dimensions" id="Medium" value="">Medium<br>
<input type="radio" class="stylebtn" name="dimensions" id="Large" value="">Large<br><br>

<button type="button" onclick="decirValue();">Submit</button>
<br>
<h4 id="dispa"></h4>
<h4 id="dispb"></h4>
<h4 id="totalprice">0 $</h4>
 </form>
```

P.S.: less global variables = less problems ;)